# cakephp 3 saving self referencing belongsToMany

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a `nodes` table and a `nodes_nodes` table.

`nodes table
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Node1  |
|  2 | Node2  |
|  3 | Node3  |
|  4 | Node4  |
|  5 | Node5  |
+----+--------+`

`nodes_nodes table
+----+----------------+---------------+
| id | parent_node_id | child_node_id |
+----+----------------+---------------+
|  1 |              2 |             3 |
|  2 |              1 |             4 |
|  3 |              1 |             5 |
+----+----------------+---------------+`

A node can have one or more parents and one or more childs

NodesTable.php:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('nodes');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsToMany('ChildNodes', [
        'className' => 'Nodes',
        'joinTable' => 'nodes_nodes',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_node_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'child_node_id'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('ParentNodes', [
        'className' => 'Nodes',
        'joinTable' => 'nodes_nodes',
        'foreignKey' => 'child_node_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'parent_node_id'
    ]);

}
```

Node.php

```
class Node extends Entity
{

    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
        'ParentNodes' => true,
        'ChildNodes' => true,
        '_joinData' => true,
    ];
}
```

NodesController.php

```
public function add()
{
    $node = $this->Nodes->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $node = $this->Nodes->patchEntity($node, $this->request->data);
        debug($node);
        if ($this->Nodes->save($node)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The node has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The node could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $nodes = $this->Nodes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('node', 'nodes'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['node']);
}
```

add.ctp form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($node) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Node') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('ParentNodes._ids', ['options' => $nodes]);
        echo $this->Form->input('ChildNodes._ids', ['options' => $nodes]);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Output of $node entity debug in add() function:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Node) {

    'name' => 'Node6',
    'ParentNodes' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '15',
            (int) 1 => '12'
        ]
    ],
    'ChildNodes' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '13'
        ]
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true,
        'ParentNodes' => true,
        'ChildNodes' => true,
        '_joinData' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'ParentNodes' => true,
        'ChildNodes' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Nodes'

}
```

When I save a new node the association is not saved.
I have tryed adding `['associated' => ['ParentNodes', 'ChildNodes']]` on `$this->Nodes->save()` with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not following the naming conventions properly. Property names for `belongsToMany` associations are by default lowercase, underscored plural variants of the association aliases, ie `parent_nodes` and `child_nodes`. In case required, this can be changed via the `propertyName` association option.

```
echo $this->Form->input('parent_nodes._ids', ['options' => $nodes]);
echo $this->Form->input('child_nodes._ids', ['options' => $nodes]);
```

Also there's no need to add the properties to `$_accessible` if you've set `*` to `true`, as that allows everything to be mass assigned.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > BelongsToMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Mass Assignment](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment)**

Comment: And it was that simple... I was so focus on the Model and Controller I didn't think to check properly the Form. The properties in `$_accessible` was a desperate move from another stack I found. Anyways, thanks a lot!