# How to do association between a table with an ID and another table using the same ID but twice

Tags: cakephp, associations, relationship, self

In cakephp, I have a table users with primary key ID and another table friends with 2 foreign keys user_id, friend_id, both indexed to the same primary key in users table. I wanna know, how the heck do I connect them in the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915954/cakephp-3-saving-self-referencing-belongstomany) show the setup you're looking for?

Comment: Basically yes thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table alias.

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Friends', [
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'friend_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinTable' => 'users_friends',
    ]);
```